# Is there a concept of DataProvider in NUnit3 like we have in TestNG?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a method that I want to call with different test data that is stored in either JSON or excel or in the form of the properties file. Is there a concept of DataProvider in NUnit like we have in TestNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit has a number of attributes, which are used to provide data to test methods. A good starting point in the documentation to see them all is https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parameterized-Tests , which links to lots of information.

All of the built-in attributes allow for data to be provided programmatically, but NUnit does **not** have any attributes that fetch the data from a file or other external source.

There are two ways that people normally deal with this:

1. Use an existing attribute (e.g. `[TestCaseSource]` and write a method that will read the external data and supply test cases.
2. Create an in-house custom attribute that takes the name of a particular type of source, opens it, reads the data and creates the test cases.

Typically, folks start out with (1), which is simpler to implement and then - if and when necessary - migrate the same code to (2) by incorporating it within a custom attribute.

For info about writing Custom Attributes (if you need to) start with https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Attributes